# Deadlock while add() and take() elements to BlockingQueue

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice, blockingqueue

I'm playing with `java.util.concurrent` package and using its interface/classes to know how they work. I created a `BlockingQueue` instance (`ArrayBlockingQueue` imlpementation). And created 50 consumers and 50 producers of `Rannable` type. Then with `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4)` created a thread pool of size 4 and submitted all of my consumers/producers to the `threadPool` (ExecutorService). But eventually printing the process I figured that it's `deadlock`-ing. Can anyone please explain why a thread safe queue gets deadlocked!? Below is my code:

**Consumer:**

```
public class ArrayBlockingQueueConsumer implements Runnable{

    BlockingQueue<Integer> blockingQueue;
    int consumerNumber = 0;

    public ArrayBlockingQueueConsumer(BlockingQueue<Integer> blockingQueue, int consumerNumber) {
        this.blockingQueue = blockingQueue;
        this.consumerNumber = consumerNumber;
    }

    public void run() {
        int i = 0;
        while(i<60) {
            System.out.printf("Consumer %d going take %d from blocking queue\n", consumerNumber, i);
            try {
                int x = blockingQueue.take();
                System.out.println("The number " + x + "is taken from the queue.");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.printf("Consumer %d interrupted while adding %d to blocking queue\n", consumerNumber, i);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

**Producer:**

```
public class ArrayBlockingQueueProducer implements Runnable{

    BlockingQueue<Integer> blockingQueue;
    int producerNumber = 0;

    public ArrayBlockingQueueProducer(BlockingQueue<Integer> blockingQueue, int producerNumber) {
        this.blockingQueue = blockingQueue;
        this.producerNumber = producerNumber;
    }

    public void run() {
        int i = 0;
        while(i<60) {
            System.out.printf("Consumer %d going to add %d to blocking queue\n", producerNumber, i);
            blockingQueue.add(i);
            System.out.printf("Consumer %d added %d to blocking queue\n", producerNumber, i);
            i++;
        }
    }

}
```

**Executor Class (main() method class):**

```
public class BlockingQueueExecutor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BlockingQueue<Integer> blockingQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>(50);

        ArrayBlockingQueueConsumer[] consumers = new ArrayBlockingQueueConsumer[200];
        ArrayBlockingQueueProducer[] producers = new ArrayBlockingQueueProducer[200];

        System.out.println("Hello hello :D");

        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
            consumers[i] = new ArrayBlockingQueueConsumer(blockingQueue, i+1);
            producers[i] = new ArrayBlockingQueueProducer(blockingQueue, i+1);
        }

        ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
            threadPool.execute(consumers[i]);
            threadPool.execute(producers[i]);
        }

        threadPool.shutdown();
    }
}
```

I ran the loops in consumers/producers from 0 to 60 so that they can throw exception when they don't find any element or find queue full respectively, ironically none of the producers/consumers threw any exception.

Comment: I ran the above code many times but didn't get that exception. But after replacing the `take()` with `remove()` in consumer code, I'm getting `NoSuchElementException` when a consumer doesn't find any element in queue (because queue is empty).

Comment: I ran it *once* and got the exception, and to be frank I don't believe your claim. The occurrence of the exception is sufficient to explain the blocking in `take()`, and there is still no evidence here whatsoever of deadlock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I ran the loops in consumers/producers from 0 to 60 so that they can throw exception when they don't find any element or find queue full respectively, ironically none of the producers/consumers threw any exception.

`take()` doesn't throw an exception when the queue is empty. It waits until an element becomes available.

> **E java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue.take() throws InterruptedException**
>
> Retrieves and removes the head of this queue, **waiting if necessary until an element becomes available**.

Comment: Ohh! Yes. That should be `remove()`.  Now it's working fine :) Thanks.
So, should I conclude that `put(o)` and `take()` can create deadlocks?
**[The link that I'm reading to understand these concepts.](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/blockingqueue.html)**

Comment: No, you should conclude that `take()` blocks when there are no elements in the queue.

Comment: @Ashish1269 They shouldn't, since if `put` waits to add an element, that means `take` has an available element to remove, and if `take` waits to remove an element, that means `put` has available space to add an element.

Comment: @Eran @EJP Using `put(o)` and `take()` creates the deadlock. The consumers keep waiting for the elements to be added to the queue while no more elements are added to the queue by producers. I used the `put(o)` and `take()` for producers and consumers.

Comment: @Ashish1269 Using put and take is the whole point of the class and is a well established pattern. The given code can't deadlock.

Answer (score 2):

There is no deadlock here. Your code threw an `IllegalStateException` for me in the `BlockingQueue.add()` call. That caused the queue not to become as full as planned, which eventually caused `take()` to *block*, as documented. Not deadlock.

A deadlock is a situation where two or more threads cannot proceed because they are all waiting for each other.

Comment: I ran the above code many times but didn't get that exception. But after replacing the take() with remove() in consumer code, I'm getting NoSuchElementException when a consumer doesn't find any element in queue (because queue is empty)

Comment: Yes this time it threw the `IllegalStateException` . Thanks for explaining me that :) Now I understand the `BlockingQueue`'s working